# How to call socket.io's emit from express.js route?

Tags: express, socket.io

I'm using express.js and socket.io and I want to achieve that when the new data arrives at one of the routes, socket emits the info to subscribers.

Something in this manner:

```
    app.get('/:id', function(req, res){
       usersFactory.add({
         id: req.params.id
       });
       //HOW TO EMIT userFactory.getAll() HERE???
       res.json({status: 'success'});
    });
```

The complete code is available here: https://gist.github.com/javascrewpt/c28565cfd307073675f3

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @What exactly is the question that you'd like help with?  And, please include the relevant code within your actual question.

Comment: I've edited my post.. hopefully, it's more understandable now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send a message to all connected sockets using socket.io, you would use:

```
io.sockets.emit(msg, data);
```

If that is not what you're trying to do, then please describe in words exactly what you want help accomplishing.

Comment: That is exactly what i need! Can you please explain why some emits are under 'connect' events (i.e. io.emit) and this one is global? Whats the difference between these two emits? Is it 'legit' to just use io.sockets emit? Thanks again!

Comment: @uglycode - If you're trying to send a message to a specific client, then you will need the specific `socket` object for that client and the usual place to have access to that is under the `connect` event.  If you're trying to send a message to all connected clients, you can do that globally from anywhere because the socket.io library has its own list of all the connected clients and `io.sockets` is a way to address all clients connected to the default namespace.